# Can *yo* be used to show possession?

Tags: pronombres

To remove the ambiguity of sentences such as

> su camisa está aquí.

we can say

> la camisa de ella está aquí.

Can this be done for the rest of the subject pronouns?

for example, rather than

> mi camisa está aquí.

can we say

> la camisa de yo está aquí.

Does it sound strange?

I know that no clarification is needed in such cases but I'm still curious to know.

Comment: You can't use *yo* after a preposition. While not strictly wrong, you rarely hear the structure for first person singular

Comment: oh yes! that's true, but what if i change *de yo* to *de mí*

Comment: By not strictly wrong, I meant when using *de mí*.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking of subject pronouns rather than prepositional pronouns thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't say that, because it's ungrammatical, and also because it's unnecessary, since the sentence is not ambiguous. *Mi camisa* means "my shirt", no ambiguity possible.

It is true that you can say *de* + pronoun to emphasize the possessor of an item (as in *la camisa de ella*), but in fact this is only ever done in the third person, either in the singular or the plural, and in both genders: *de él, de ellos, de ella, de ellas*.

Also note that the full third person personal pronouns are particular in a sense: they are the same when they act as the subject of a sentence and when they act as an object. When following a preposition (like *de* or *para*), you have to use pronouns in their object form. Since *ella* is the same as a subject and as an object, you don't notice any change here.

The same happens to the other plural pronoun: *nosotros*, *vosotros* and *ustedes* also remain the same when following prepositions.

But the other pronouns are not like this: for example, *yo* works as a subject, but as an object you must use *mí*; and *tú* changes to *ti*. So you would never say **de yo*. You could say *de mí*, but as I said before, that's never done in this particular sense (when talking of something you possess).⁽¹⁾

This is not all that different from English. In English you don't say *"this belongs to I", but "this belongs to **me**", using the object pronoun *me* instead of the subject pronoun *yo*. Of course, in English you also have different object forms for the third person (*him, her, them*).

If you want to emphasize possession, outside the third person, you instead use the full possessive pronoun, in the appropriate number and gender: *la camisa **mía***.

You can also do this in the third person, but not to resolve the ambiguity: instead of *la camisa de ella* you can equally well say *la camisa **suya***, but *suya* is totally ambiguous (it might mean "his", "her" or "their").

⁽¹⁾ You can say *de mí* in other cases ([NGLE 18.4](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bMyOgTpAfdofEirf)), typically when *de* + pronoun is a complement of certain verbs (*«¿Te acuerdas de mí?»*, *«No te alejes de mí.»*, etc.), and also when you want to emphasize even more: *de mí mismo*, lit. "of me myself".

Comment: You might want to emphasize the in this particular sense, because the possessive *de mí* (and especially when modified with  *mismo/a*)  **does** work other cases.  (see the Gramática 18.4)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you if it is strictly wrong, but I ensure you that in Spain where I live NOBODY would say that, and everybody will think it is wrong. The same for "la camisa de mi".

Answer (score 0):

No.

It is possible to speak of

> Su camisa de ella

when we want to clarify whose shirt it is, given that "su" is ambiguous without a clear context.

But in this position in the sentence, "ella" is not the subject.  It is an *object pronoun* in this case.  What is tricky here for a Spanish learner is that for the feminine third person singular, the object pronoun and the subject pronoun use the *same word*: "ella."

Here is a list of all the object pronouns:

> mí
>
> tí
>
> él, ella, ello
>
> nosotros
>
> vosotros
>
> ellos, ellas, ustedes

As you can see, "yo" is not in this list.  Instead, the correct form is "mí."  Therefore, it is theoretically possible to talk of

> la camisa de mí

However, I haven't off hand been able to come up with a realistic usage of this combination of words, because any attempt to clarify or emphasize that it is *my* shirt will look something like this:

> la camisa mía

But at least you now have the correct form, even if it is only academic, and not something that you would use under normal circumstances.